Using dynamic identity block as output for RBAC assignment
I have this in my module configuration:
main.tf
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlsrv" {

  dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.identity == null ? [] : [true]
    content {
      type         = lookup(var.identity, "type", null)
      identity_ids = lookup(var.identity, "identity_ids", null)
    }
  }
}

variable.tf
variable "identity" {
  type        = any
  description = <<EOT
    type = Specifies the type of Managed Service Identity that should be configured on the Cognitive Account. Possible values are SystemAssigned, UserAssigned, SystemAssigned, UserAssigned (to enable both).
    identity_ids = A list of IDs for User Assigned Managed Identity resources to be assigned.
  EOT
  default     = null
}

output.tf
output "identity" {
  description = "Identity of the Azure SQL Database"
  value       = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlsrv.identity
}

and in resource itself:
azuresql.tf
module "sql-dataintelligence" {
  source = "../../../modules/azure_sql"

  identity = {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

What I'm attempting to do now, is use the created Managed Identity from azuresql.tf, to give it RBAC assignment on Storage Account I'm creating:
sa.tf
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sql-storage-blob-reader" {
  scope                = module.mta-adls-dataintelligence.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Reader"
  principal_id         = module.sql-dataintelligence.identity[0].principal_id
}

However, plan fails with following:
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with azurerm_role_assignment.sql-storage-blob-reader,
│   on mtdta_data_lake_gen_2.tf line 41, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sql-storage-blob-reader":
│   41:   principal_id         = module.sql-dataintelligence.identity[0].principal_id
│ 
│ The argument "principal_id" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Seems like Terraform is not "seeing" that it should wait, for module.sql-dataintelligence to be created and then use identity that gets created in a process.
Tried to explicitly add depends_on = [module.sql-dataintelligence] but without any luck.
First attempts with dynamic blocks, so I might be missing something

Later edit:
I also tried to define a seperate output in azuresql.tf
output "identity" {
  value = module.sql-dataintelligence.identity
}

just to make sure what potentially gets returned and a value is:
Changes to Outputs:
  + identity = [
      + {
          + identity_ids = null
          + principal_id = null
          + tenant_id    = null
          + type         = "SystemAssigned"
        },
    ]

so looks like, Terraform outputs a value for the variable, not what gets created in a process (I would expect something along side "principal_id = (known after apply)")

Please add how you are calling the module to the question.

@MarkoE added,hopefully this is what you meant ^^

Yeah, that's it. Can you define another output for principal_id that would be something along the lines of value = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserv.identity[0].principal_id? And then use it for the principal_id argument.

"The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no elements."

Tried attempting to specify output in azuresql.tf (see later edit). So it seems that output.tf in module outputs a variable value, instead of object that gets created in a process

Was the MSSQL server created successfully at all?

Yes, it's currently existing so just changing the configuration to add a Identity (using dynamic block since we want to have Identity for this specific MSSQL) [got 4 in total]. After setting System Assigned Managed Identity manually using Azure Portal, principal_id gets retrieved successfully, but that's of course not the ideal scenario to have to click something in Portal :D


Terraform outputs a value for the variable, not what gets created in a process (I would expect something along side "principal_id = (known after apply)"):

Thanks to @Marko E for pointing towards the same direction I was considering. Use a separate output block to obtain the principal_id value from the identity list of values from the azurerm_mssql_server server instead of retrieving directly from the dynamic "identity" block.
Use below provided block in outputs.tf:
output "sql_server_id" {
  description = "The ID of the created Azure SQL Server."
  value       = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlsrv.id
}

output "sql_server_identity" {
  description = "The identity block of the Azure SQL Server."
  value       = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlsrv.identity
}
output "principal_id"{
  description = "principal_id value"
  value = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlsrv.identity[0].principal_id
}



The null is replaced by the exact value of principal_id value as shown above in the output image.
Now, I tried creating a role assignment with the given scope worked as expected.
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sql-storage-blob-reader" {
  scope                = xxxxx
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Reader"
  principal_id         = azurerm_mssql_server.example.identity[0].principal_id
}



Note: If still the issue persists with the module block, add depends_on block in the resource "azurerm_role_assignment" to add the dependency and it will work as expected.

What I noticed (and I think it may be a bug) is that it's not working only when Terraform's action would be to create Managed Identity on existing resource that does not have it. Re-creating resource, creating a new resource next to existing with exactly same setup or when I set MI manually in Portal and TF would need to use it - works perfectly fine. It's this one specific scenario that it's not working as intended. I ended up with enabling MI directly in Portal and let TF do its things after that

Have you tried the above setup once! @glaeran

Yes, copied your outputs 1:1, ended up with similar scenario that I explained earlier. Have in mind that in my initial setup (that I explained in original post) my SQL already exists and I've built Identity on top of it. As I explained in previous comment - both yours and @MarkoE approaches, work perfectly fine on new resources

Then why can't u go with the new resource deployments? Is it not meeting your requirement! @glaeran
